# How to control cache in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I am working on e-commerce website build on Php, But I am not using Apache as a server, Rather then I created my own custom server script Like this :

I have Index.php Where I put all my routes, It is working fine but When I try to implement cache control, It won't apply.

Here is the directory structure:

```html
--src
  --public
    --index.php
    --.htaccess
  --views
```

I think my .htaccess file is not working as I want to, No images, css, js is cache into memory

Here is the .htaccess code

```html
# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Connection keep-alive
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `.htaccess` is an apache file. So you must be using apache, even though you say you aren't?

Comment: What does _"But I am not using Apache as a server, Rather then I created my own custom server script Like this"_ mean? Are you saying you built your own web server using PHP?

Comment: I use this https://joshtronic.com/2015/05/24/basic-page-routing-in-php/ to do routing in php

Comment: What does routing have to do with _"not using Apache"_? Apache is the _web server_ that takes the request from the clients and pass it along to your application than happens to be written in PHP, which handles the routing.

Comment: I install Xampp But I am not stating its Apache Server to boot up my Application, Rather than I open my cmd and type this, **php -S localhost:3000**

Comment: Why not just run Apache that comes with XAMPP? If you're not running Apache, then you won't be able to use `.htaccess`, since that's an Apache specific file.

Comment: Since I already build my full application, so this time is not possible to rebuild the application, Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Beware that [PHP built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) is not intended to be used on production servers. You can't just decouple from Apache—you need to either actively support whatever replacement server you want or discard features that aren't 100% PHP.